# UIImageView is not visible after app was submitted to Apple Store

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

i've got this problem:
i created an app and tested it, everything worked fine. So i submitted to the app store and when i downloaded it from the store i found that an UIImageView is blank, but when i re-tested it on xcode, both on simulator and on real device, it worked!
The problem could be that the imageView has the same size of the whole screen?i mean even the status bar is covered, because i meant to create continuity from the launchImage to the first View. I need to create an update as soon as possible what can i do to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check to see that the image was included in the app bundle?

Comment: Try testing in your app in the release-configuration instead debug configuration

Comment: @Aaron you mean something like to check the "copy in app folder" when adding the image to xcode right? If so i think i did because it's checked by default, anyway i'll try to delete the image then re-copy in xcode and upload again. So the problem should not be related to the Imageview size right?

Comment: Not sure about the image size. The first place to check is the copy bundle resources section of the project.

Answer (score 1):

What most likely happened is that the image that was being presented by the `imageView` was not included with the app files / app bundle.